# Checking for duplicates in database table before inserting

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

I need to create a form that gathers a first name, last name, and an email address. I have created a table in MySQL called `guestbook`. The table looks something like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE guestbook (
    id int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    firstName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    lastName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    email varchar(250) NOT NULL,
    status int NOT NULL,
    sort int NOT NULL
);
```

And here is my code thus far:

```
<?php

Global $Conn;
$Conn = new mysqli("localhost","151_millet","2gZMXYGC","GUESTBOOK");

if(!$Conn) {
    $ErrorMsg = "Couldn't connect to the database";
}

$FName = $_POST["fname"];
$LName = $_POST["lname"];
$Email = $_POST["email"];

// The series of ifs below tests to see if each field is blank
// If it is blank it will output an error message for each that is blank
if($FName == "") {
    $ErrorMsg .= "First Name Was Left Blank<br>";
}

if($LName == "") {
    $ErrorMsg .= "Last Name Field Was Left Blank.<br>";
}

if($Email == "") {
    $ErrorMsg .="Email field was left blank.<br>";
}
```

I have no idea how to check for duplicates in the email field. Any help would be appreciated. I think I need to come up with a way to test $_POST against whats already in the db.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a place to get help *after* you've tried to do something. It's not a place to come to get work done for you. You must show what you've done, what specific problem you're trying to solve, and you must also make sure you've already tried to look on the site for a solution by using the search functionality. We're not here to do your coursework for you!

Comment: I have tried, i have three different files done. I'm developing a ticket system at work,I already work int he field, I just can't grasp how to check for duplicates and can't find a solution to output to txt files.... Would it help if i upload my code?

Comment: Yes, it absolutely would be helpful. There's not a real question here, it seems more like a specification for something to build. We don't know what you have already done, or what specific problem you're trying to solve. If you're trying to simply learn PHP and MySQL then this probably isn't the right place I'm sorry to say.

Comment: edit done upload the processing part of my code, im in no way trying to learn syntax, I need the logic behind testing against the db with an incoming $_POST

Comment: Okay, we're getting better. What have you tried so far to make this work? Any attempt at all would do as a starting point. If we can identify a specific problem, then we can probably edit your question to focus on that particular problem.

Comment: Ive used a select sql statement "SELCT `email` from GUESTBOOK WHERE `email`=$Email LIMIT 1" if that happens then the result would mean that email already exists....

Comment: Okay, be sure to add that to the question, things like that will get buried in these comments! :) I'll help clean up your question a bit, and make it a bit more focused.

Comment: Is the edited version better? :) I realize now that you guys don't want all the garbage that is irrelevant my question. Lesson learned. I looked like an absolute noob lol

Comment: Take a look now, your version was much better, but we need to get as much info in there as possible! :) You may need to tweak that SQL slightly so it closer matches what your database table actually is like.

Answer (score 1):

Alrighty, now we've cleaned up this question a bit. Let's get down to business.

You want to check for duplicates in your database. There are a couple of things you need to do for this. Let's try to keep this as simple as possible while we're working on it too.

First off, it's good to see you're using MySQLi and not the deprecated mysql_* functions. But we can handle MySQLi in a more object oriented manner. Also, using globals is frowned upon (and is actually not necessary, even in your current code!)

One other thing to note is that there are slightly different styles of code used in modern PHP, like camel case, and how you format if statements. If you're interested in learning PHP, then you should take a look at the PHP-FIG PSRs.

```
<?php

$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "151_millet", "2gZMXYGC", "GUESTBOOK");

if ($conn->connect_errno) {
    // This is an error that will stop us from continuing, so assigning
    // the error message to a string, doesn't really help us in this case
    // The application NEEDS to stop
    throw new RuntimeException("Unable to connect to MySQL database.");
}

$firstName = $_POST["fname"];
$lastName  = $_POST["lname"];
$email     = $_POST["email"];

if (!$firstName || !$lastName || !$email) {
    echo "Please make sure to fill in all of your details.";

    // You may want to handle this differently, this is just to keep things
    // Very simple
    exit;
}

$query = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM guestbook WHERE email = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$count = 0;

if ($stmt) {
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

    $count = $stmt->num_rows;

    $stmt->close();
}

if ($count > 0) {
    echo "A user with that email address already exists.";
    exit;
}

// Do other stuff
```

That should help you out with what you need to do to check if an email address already exists. But you should also enforce this in your database by adding a *unique key* to the email column. That will mean that even if your code fails and would allow a duplicate email address entry, your database won't.